# hide subdirectory from url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have following directory structure

```
Root(www.example.com)/
                  index.php(simple page with links pointing to subdirectory like www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php?id=1)
                  subdirectory/
                              index.php
                              .htaccess(handling all subdirectory rewriting and working fine)
```

so my current url is

```
www.example.com/subdirectory/10/
```

so i want to hide the 'subdirectory' from the the url so the final url should look like

```
www.example.com/10/
```

i have tried by adding following rule in my subdirectory/.htaccess file but its not working

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^$ subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1
```

my subdirectory/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                              

RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?\.html  index.php?view=showad&adid=$7&cityid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/page([0-9]*)\.html   index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1&page=$7 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-]?[0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/posts/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?/([0-9]+)([-_][^/]*)?     index.php?view=ads&catid=$3&subcatid=$5&cityid=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: i don't have any .htaccess in my root

Comment: ok good then please show `subdirectory/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava i have added my subdirectory/.htaccess file in the main post

Answer (score 0):

In your `subdirectory/.htaccess`, insert these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/

# external redirect from actual URL to a pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdirectory/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

# remaining rules go below this
```

You will also need these rules in your site's root .htaccess (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ subdirectory/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L]
```